# Getting field names from QueryResult when child records are empty - How does Workbench do it?

Tags: apex, rest-api, workbench

I'm querying via the REST API (in Apex, because I'm calling another org, amongst other reasons) and using a wacky recursive algorithm on the first returned record to parse out the field names. And no, for my purposes, I *cannot* parse the fields names from the query string, for a multitude of reasons.

**Sample query**

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Firstname, Account.Id From Contacts) FROM Account LIMIT 2
```

**My result when all is well. This is what I'm looking for.**

```
"fieldToObjectWrapper": {
    "null": {
        "Name": "Account"
    }, 
    "Contacts": {
        "Contact.Account.Id": "Account", 
        "Contacts.FirstName": "Contact"
    }
}
```

My problem comes when the first returned record has no child records. The child node doesn't exist, so I can't parse the fields.

**QueryResult with a "good" first record**

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "url": "/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0016100000W5K09AAF", 
    "type": "Account"
  }, 
  "Name": "Company A", 
  "Contacts": {
    "totalSize": 1, 
    "done": true, 
    "records": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Whoever", 
        "attributes": {
          "url": "/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Contact/0036100001aVoyOAAS", 
          "type": "Contact"
        }, 
        "Account": {
          "attributes": {
            "url": "/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0016100000W5K09AAF", 
            "type": "Account"
          }, 
          "Id": "0016100000W5K09AAF"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "url": "/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0016100000W5K0AAAV", 
    "type": "Account"
  }, 
  "Name": "Company B"
}
```

But imagine if Company B came first. No Contacts so no fields to parse.

It dawned on me that the Workbench must be doing something similar to display its query results so I dug into the open source code. My PHP is... lacking... but from what I can tell, they're actually doing the same thing (which made me feel good about myself). They're taking the first record from the results and parsing out the names.

https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/master/workbench/async/QueryFutureTask.php

On line 237, in *createQueryResultTable*, they're passing *$records[0]* into *getQueryResultHeaders*, which then calls itself recursively as it loops through the fields.

But in the Workbench, it works. (Maybe that's why they call it the *Work*bench...) They get the field names regardless of whether the first record contains child records or not.

[image]

How do they do that? What am I missing? Is there another way?

Thanks very much!

**UPDATE**
Question answered in the comments. Thanks to all for playing!

Comment: In subquery, we already provided the fields name (`Firstname, Account.Id`). Can't we create table header using these fields?

Comment: Can you show us an actual example from the workbench? What feature are you talking about in Workbench? As far as I can tell, it doesn't show anything if there are no child records--each row in the query result is rendered independently.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've added a Workbench screenshot. I know each result is rendered independently, but surely they only grab the the headers once? Hmm. Then again... Okay. So they're doing it while they render each row.. rather than what I'm doing.. which is getting all my headers at the start. Maybe that's it.

Comment: @PragatiJain As I mention in my opening, there are many reasons (that I won't get into) that I won't get the headers from the query itself, but thank you.

Comment: @David Precisely that. They literally dump a new table inside the table cell of the parent. There's no special magic going on here.

Comment: @sfdcfox And I was trying to be efficient. My mistake. Thanks, as always!

Comment: @David If I were doing what I think you're trying to do, I'd use a global `Map<String, Set<String>>` variable to keep track of already populated fields by child, and the wrapper itself would use a Map to represent fields, but you'd still have to take a second pass to populate the remaining maps to avoid "key not found" VF errors.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yep. I've already got a similar map going! Getting each subtable's headers independently now makes sense to me... but I now I'm worried about getting the primary table's headers, like "Contacts". Seems to me I'd still have to go through all the records once to just get that. Or I'm just over-tired.. (And I'm using Lightning. I'm never using VF again if I can avoid it. Actually, this project started as a Lightning learning exercise..)

Comment: @sfdcfox Though for the primary headers, like Contacts, I do have the object describes handy.. and I lowercase the childRelationship names as I bring 'em in, so I suppose I can parse the query string for those subquery objects and get the childSobject name from that... maybe.